# Why isn't this test SQL injection returning all rows in the table?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

I was trying to follow [this example](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) on a local webpage I run using WAMP. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Testing SQL injection</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', 'St@ck0verflow');
if(!$link)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
if(!mysql_select_db('opentarget', $link))//arguments are in revere order compared to mysqli
    die('Could not select database');
// a good user's name
$name = "Onetwo"; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name'";
echo "Normal: " . $query . "<br />";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "Result: <pre>";
print_r(mysql_fetch_row($result));
echo "</pre><br /><br />";
// user input that uses SQL Injection
$name_bad = "' OR 1'"; 

// our MySQL query builder, however, not a very safe one
$query_bad = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name_bad'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
// display what the new query will look like, with injection
echo "Injection: " . $query_bad.'<br />Result: <pre>';
print_r(mysql_fetch_row($result));
echo '</pre>';
echo '<br />Any errors? '.mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The first query runs as expected but when I print the result of the second one it is the same as the first. I thought it would print out all the contents of the table? What exactly does `OR 1` do?

I tried running the bad query directly in MySQL from the command line, and unless I'm doing something wrong I get the empty set (which is different than the results displayed in PHP).

Comment: Please do some code formating so that i can understand what you have coded

Comment: 1) your injection should be `' OR 1--` or `' OR '1'='1`, 2) you'll only get one row because you only ever fetch one row 3) as noted elsewhere, your second query needs to be `mysql_query($query_bad)`.

Comment: @GigaWatt 1)could you explain why it should be that? Is the goal to write a condition that is always true? If yes, why not just have `1` or `TRUE`? 2)fixed 3)fixed

Comment: Yep, the goal is to make a condition always true (so it returns every row).
If you use `' OR 1'` your query will end `'' OR 1'` which has mismatching quotes.  The `--` makes the rest of the query a comment, so `1 OR 1--` becomes `username = '' OR 1` when executed.  Alternately, `' OR '1'='1` becomes `username = '' OR '1'='1'`.  Given that `'1'='1'` is always true, it works and prevents mismatched quotes.

Comment: @GigaWatt "The `--` makes the rest of the query a comment" small but critical mistake. `--  ` makes the rest of the statement a comment, without the space you get an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
$query_bad = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name_bad'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

See how your SQL string variable is different to the variable you put in the query function?  You are building `$query_bad` but passing `$query` to the `mysql_query()` function.

Comment: [argh!](http://www.infidelityhelpgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Mistake.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

OR 1 Always evaluates to true because 1=TRUE in PHP.

So basically it is trying to show you what happens when someone puts bad text into some piece of data you are using in a query...

Your original query was

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name'
```

But that name variable might be set to this phrase:

```
' OR 1'
```

So you just piece those together and will see that instead of returning just the username you want, SQL will return and username that is a) '' [blank], or b) Anything (Because each time 1=TRUE so the row is returned).

**EDITED - Added below line to help clarify**

To simplify this better, imagine the sql server looking for data. It will look at each row and run that `WHERE` statement. So it hits row 1 and asks `does username = "harry"?`. It will then return the row if this is true, or skip the row if it is false.

Now, Lets say you load $name from an input box on a web form. I might enter "Harry" or "Tom" or whatever. These are all valid. But what if I instead enter `Harry' OR TRUE`. On every row, SQL is asking `Does username='Harry' OR TRUE` Of course it probably evaluates Username=Harry to false, but the logical expression returns true because the second part is always true.

```
(0 OR 1) is always evaluated to TRUE.
```

I hope that helps clarify.

Also, check out this link to understand injection attacks better... http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: "OR 1 Always evaluates to true because 1=TRUE in PHP." I don't quite follow. Why not just put `1` or `TRUE`?

Comment: Ok, I have updated my explanation to help you out a bit. I hope it clarifies what is going on there.